# WPF Set controltemplate for only first level

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate

I have a style for tabcontrol :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="CloseableTabControl">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
```

this have effect for all tabitem contained into tabcontrol, including item of child tabcontrol.

I want that only first level tabitems have applicated the style.
How I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't set value `x:Key` for the TabItem style, hence it gets applied to all TabItems found in the Visual Tree. In case you want the style to be applied to only specific TabItems you need to set the x:Key value -

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"
       x:Key="TabItemStyle">
```

And wherever you want the Style to be applied, you have to use `StaticResource`-

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"/>
```